# Help converting XmlNode to DataSet/DataTable, from SharePoint Web Services, Lists.asmx

Tags: list, web-services, caml-query, sharepoint-calendar, conversion

This is my first post here, but used this site a lot :)

My question is how I can convert an XmlNode, obtained through the Lists.asmx SharePoint web service, to a DataSet / DataTable. The reason I want a DataTable with the events is because we have a lot of extension methods helping extracting values and such in an allready implemented class.

I am asking the service for events from a calendar. This is how I use the service:

```
/* Instantiate an XmlDocument object */
var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
query.InnerXml = "<Where>" +
                    "<And>" +
                        string.Format("<Geq><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"TRUE\">{0}</Value></Geq>", SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(from)) +
                        string.Format("<Leq><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\" IncludeTimeValue=\"TRUE\">{0}</Value></Leq>", SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(to)) +
                    "</And>" +
                 "</Where>";
queryOptions.InnerXml = "";
viewFields.InnerXml = GetViewFields();

nodeListItems =
    serviceClient.GetListItems
    (listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);
```

I searched the great webz and found this thread which is exactly what I want to achieve. In the thread a guy posted this method and people rejoiced, saying it solved it:

```
public static DataSet ConverttYourXmlNodeToDataSet(XmlNode xmlnodeinput)
{
    //declaring data set object
    DataSet dataset = null;
    if (xmlnodeinput!= null)
    {
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(xmlnodeinput.OuterXml, XmlNodeType.Element, null);
        dataset = new DataSet();
        dataset.ReadXml(xtr);
    }

    return dataset;
}
```

But for me it does not seem to do the trick. The XmlTextReader just says "None" when I debug it. I also tried using XmlNodeReader instead of XmlTextReader. When I check what the OuterXml in the node is, it looks like this:

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<rs:data ItemCount="4">
   <z:row .. Attributes />
   <z:row .. Attributes />
   <z:row .. Attributes />
   <z:row .. Attributes />
</rs:data>
</listitems>
```

The rows are the 4 events I wanted to get, with lots of attributes on them. I guess it looks like it should markup-wise?

Can anyone help me out? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this will load xml data into  Datset.

```
 XmlNode nodeListItems = objlist.GetListItems(_ListName, null, null, null, null, null, null);

 xmlDoc.LoadXml(nodeListItems.OuterXml);

 XmlNodeReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);

 ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
```